# How to check if the uibutton is pressed via tag?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 50, height: 50))    
button.tag = 15    
view.addSubview(button)
```

Comment: You need to provide more information than this code snippet. What are you trying to achieve? What have you already tried?

Comment: @ganzogo I need when the uibutton with tag 15 is pressed to perform a segue programmatically, not in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You should add the target of the button, like this:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

And the function could go like this:

```
func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 15 {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @grandadmiral accept this answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
func addANewButton() {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 1, y: 1, width: 50, height: 50))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(action(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
    button.tag = 15
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func action(_ sender: UIButton) {
    switch sender.tag {
    case 15: //Do something
    case 16: //Do something else
    //Add as many cases you want...
    default: break
}
```

The function `action` gets called whenever a button for which you have added a target is pressed.

Comment: this won't work, because button is announced in one function and can't be used in viewdidload or smth like that.

Comment: In this case put the code from `viewDidLoad()` just inside the function in which you create and add the button the the view.

Comment: @grandadmiral check out the changed I have made to the code